# nhibernate lazy loading and recursive saving

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have been using the technique in nhibernate where in if i save the parent class object the child classes objects related to it are oso saved. If i remove any object from the collection they wer deleted from db as well.

But Recently i have modified my code to disable lazy loading and since then the recursive saving doesnt work.

Can any one tell me what is it that i m missing. i have tried to search but the solutions i found dint really work out for me.

I have the domain class similar to the one below

```
public class Class1
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Class2> Class2Seq { get; set; }
}
public class Class2
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Class1 Class1Ref{ get; set; }
}
```

The mapping classes are similar to these

```
public class Class1Map: ClassMap<Class1>
{
    public Class1Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Class2Seq)
            .KeyColumn("Class1Id")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class Class2Map: ClassMap<Class2>
{
    public Class2Map()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Class1Ref).Column("Class1Id").Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like

```
parent.Remove(child);
session.SaveOrUpdate(parent);
session.Flush()
```

your mapping needs to be:

```
HasMany(x => x.Class2Seq)
            .KeyColumn("Class1Id")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: ok. but DeleteOrphan is required for remove()... without that the saveorupdate() should work isn't it?

Comment: yes it should, as in parent.add(child) - as long as you've set child.parent

Comment: Yes i have set child.parent and as i mentioned it worked perfectly fine until i disabled lazy load.

Comment: I have issues in the past with the collection not being initialized properly when the collection hasnt been fetched with a left join - could you add a .Fetch.Join() to your mapping and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: i have tried adding .Fetch.Join() but that results in duplicate records being fetched at the other places.

Comment: your queries would need a .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)